# Irreducible Representation and the center of a group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Hi I was wondering if someone could help me/hint along the right path.

Let $\rho:G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation. Let $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$. Show that if $a\in Z(G)$, then $\rho(a) =\lambda *I$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $g\in G$ be an arbitrary element. Then, one can see $ga=ag$. Thus, $\rho (ag)=\rho(ga)$ and so $\rho(g)\rho(a)=\rho(a)\rho(g)$. By Schur Lemma, $\rho(a)=\lambda I$, as desired.